Confidence interval for a normal RV that its std is the mean of a different normal RV
Question:
Suppose $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_X,a),Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,b\cdot\mu_X)$ where $a$ and $b$ are known, but $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ are not. What confidence bounds can we give for $\mu_Y$ from one observation of $x\sim X$ and $y\sim Y$?
The confidence bounds of $\mu_Y$ need to be a function of $a,b,x$ and $y$.
Assumption:
$X>0$ (its negative values are negligible). If you wish, it is a truncated normal distribution.
My attempt:
Since $\mu_X$ is unknown, and only $a$ is known, given $x$ from $X$, we know that with $d_1\%$ confidence (for example $d_1=95$), $x\in[\mu_X-a\cdot Z_{d_1},\infty]$, or in other words we can bound $\mu_X\leq x+a\cdot Z_{d_1}$, with the corresponding $Z$-score.
This means that with $d_1\%$ confidence, we can bound the standard deviation of $Y$: $\sigma_Y\leq b\cdot(x+a\cdot Z_{d_1})$.
Now given $y$ from $Y$, After we have a bound for $\mu_X$, we can say that with $d_2\%$ confidence,
\begin{equation}\mu_y\in[y-b\cdot(x+a\cdot Z_{d_1})\cdot Z_{\frac{d_2+100}{2}}, y+b\cdot(x+a\cdot Z_{d_1})\cdot Z_{\frac{d_2+100}{2}}]\end{equation}
With the total confidence being $100\cdot\frac{d_1}{100}\cdot\frac{d_2}{100}\%$.
Questions about my attempt:

I feel like the last part is not accurate, I bounded $\sigma_y$ from above, do I then need to integrate over all possible values of $\sigma_y$ or can I use just one probability distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_y, b\cdot(x+a\cdot Z_{d_1}))$?
I've seen different ways of working with two confidence intervals like in this question using the Delta Method. But, since it is not a product of two parameters, but one parameter is a function of the other, I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Thanks @MattF.! You're right. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Hi @MattF. thank you for your comment. I don't understand why the first inequality is correct and how this leads to an answer. We can say that $$P\left[|X-\mu_x|<a\cdot Z_{95}\right]>0.9$$ and/or $$P\left[|X-\mu_X|<|x-\mu_X|\right]=F_X(\mu_X+|X-\mu_x|)-F_X(\mu_X-|X-\mu_x|)$$ with F being the comulative distribution, but I don't see how you can deduce a probability from it. For the second inequality, $\mu_x$ is fixed but unknown.. what do you mean by "there exist"?
I'm looking for an answer that is a function of $a,b,x$ and $y$.

This looks ad hoc.  Have you considered a likelihood ratio test?
